# How to update a dynamically created Angular Material Component's property binding (e.g. ProgressBar or Spinner)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-renderer2

#### Description

I want to create and control a Material ProgressBar from within a directive.

#### Problem

I can't update the ProgressBar's `value` property (though everything else, for example the `mode`).

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-progress-bar-directive?file=src/app/progress.directive.ts

#### Notes

The MatSpinner shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like it might be a bug. I've tried a couple of things with 0 luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug; I just found the related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18676

There is also a PR ready, so this should be fixed in one of the upcoming releases.

There is no workaround by now.